# initialize a string size during declaration

Tags: c++11

suppose I have a class like this and I would like to create a string with a 
specific capacity. I tried doing the following but that did not work.
Any suggestions ? I know I could do it in the constructor but would like to do it during the declaration if possible.

```
class foo
{
 std::string bar = std::string().resize(45);
}
```

I get the error

main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:8:46: error: conversion from 'void' to non-scalar type 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string}' requested
     std::string test =   std::string().resize(45);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++, you probably don't want to "chain" methods unless previous methods have the correct return type.

As suggested by @James Maa, you can do simply use the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In c++11 we have new feature called `move constructor` so

```
string str = string();
```

doesn't cause extra time.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor

with move constructor, the program would directly use the address of the temporary constructed string after `=` sign, without making a copy.

The problem is that `resize()`function in c++ actually returns `void`

---

```
basic_string( size_type count, 
              CharT ch, 
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

This constructor might be something you are directly interested in.

You can do something with

```
std::string str(45, ' ');
```

Comment: You should mention that the constructor you reference does more than just allocation. (Admittedly so does resize.)